# Robotframework + Process + Log timestamp

Tags: robotframework

I would understand how to properly display logs of a Python process executed in Roboframework.

Let's suppose that *${result1.stdout}* is this one:

```
*INFO:1536834347873* ciao ciao
*INFO:1536834347883* ciao ciao2
```

Is it possibile to transform them in two robotframework logs **with the right date**? If I use the "Log keyword" they will have the keywork execution timestamp...

Rr

Note: I'm executing the python script with "start process". I need this because I need to run in parallel multiple scripts

```
|   | Start Process | python .${/}files${/}testPython.py | alias=First | shell=yes | stderr=/tmp/provaerr1.log | stdout=/tmp/prova1.log | 
|   | ${result1}= | Wait For Process | First |
|   | Log | ${result1.stdout}
```

|

Comment: No idea what the problem is. I always get proper date&time in logs. How do you get that timestamp?

Comment: Modified the question with more details

Comment: If you get the timestamp from a python script, you could format it in that script.

Comment: Didn't get your answer. Could you eleaborate?